# Return scalar-value after WITH sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a function that returns 0 or 1. How to do it, if I use WITH-construction in my code

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[IsBossFull] (@bossFull int, @user int)
RETURNS bit 
AS
BEGIN
          ;WITH CTE
            AS (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM [USERS] WHERE [Id] = @user
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT U.*
                    FROM CTE C
                        INNER JOIN [USERS] u on U.[Id] = C.[Chief]
                )
                -- then something like
                if exists(
                select * from cte where id = @bossFull)
                return 1
                else return 0
END
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff I use `WITH` because I need recursion

Comment: Can you post sample data of what's in the USERS table & what output you expect? It's not obvious from your question why you need recursion if you're matching an id. Why can't you just find all direct subordinates of a boss id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would assign the value to a variable and return that:

```
DECLARE @retval int;

WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT *
      FROM USERS
      WHERE Id = @user
      UNION ALL
      SELECT U.*
      FROM CTE C INNER JOIN
           USERS u 
           ON U.[Id] = C.[Chief]
     )
SELECT @retval = COUNT(*)
FROM cte
WHERE id = @bossfull;

RETURN(@retval);
```

I haven't actually simplified the code.  You can stop the recursion when `@bossful` is actually found.

If you really want, you can use `return(case when retval > 0 then 1 else 0 end)`.  However, `@retval` cannot be greater than 1, because that would imply cycles in the hierarchy -- and the CTE would not return.

Comment: He only wants a 1 or 0. True or False. If he wanted a count of all descendents no matter how many levels deep, recursion would make sense. But True/False indicates he just wants to check for the existence of something. So why recurse through other levels if you can find it directly?

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use `SET @retval = (select ...)` instead of `SELECT @retval = Count ...`

Comment: @robertdeniro This is not so important for me. The hierarchy depth of 3-4 levels. I was thinking to use a cursor. Recursion to terminate by testing the CTE table to contents `@bossFull`

Comment: @Gordon Linoff while I waited, I used the table function that returns a table hierarchy. Interesting fact - it works 30% faster. `dbo.IsBossFull(@user, @userBoss) = 1` ~60 ms, `exists(select * from dbo.BossFull(@user) where id = @userBoss)` ~40 ms.